# Reg ex find and replace with groups

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-group

I'm trying to find the screen names in each line of text eg. screen_name: CoinLibre2009. After finding every screen name I have to replace each screen name with the original first character then exactly four asterisks (****) and then the last character. For example the screen name CoinLibre2009 would become C****9. I'm thinking that I need to use groups and that I should include the "screen_name: " in my find, and just include it back in with the replace.

Here are a few lines of the text I'm working with:

```
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:09    text: Today we can see positive trends for growth, but will there be a new fall? crypto screen_name: Ksandimo   location: null  verified: false followers_count: 1597   friends_count: 17   lang: ru    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:14    text: 8745.02$ per now  screen_name: CoinLibre2009  location: Free World    verified: false followers_count: 113    friends_count: 110  lang: ru    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:16    text: Current price of is $8745.02  screen_name: bitcoinavg location: null  verified: false followers_count: 44 friends_count: 9    lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:25    text: Think weve hit resistance for Bitcoin now. Will it fully recover? Im not sure screen_name: jasongaved location: Brighton & Hove / London  verified: false followers_count: 1996   friends_count: 1967 lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:28    text: Today's price is $8745.02 as of February 3, 2018 at 11:59AM   screen_name: FR33Q  location: Europe    verified: false followers_count: 1164   friends_count: 1998 lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
```

Also here is a screenshot of what the data looks like in notepad ++:
[image]

I'm using reg ex in Notepad++ for this task. Here is what I have come up with so far. screen_name:\s[A-Za-z0-9]+ Then this is where I get stuck, as I'm not sure how to replace the first and last characters.

Comment: Please share your attempts.

Comment: @HassanImam ok will do!

Comment: Are there tabs or only spaces? Is the original format really plain text or maybe HTML/XML/JSON?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer there are both tabs and spaces. It actually is a plain text format. This is for an assignment, so the text file they gave us was purposely confusing and formatted strange, and we have to use reg ex to clean it up.

Comment: @Brad Since the tabs might make separating the segments easier, you might want to mark them in your example (or add a text description).

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer the tabs are located before each data value (eg. screen_name, location, friends_count etc).

Comment: Try `screen_name:\s[A-Za-z0-9]\K[A-Za-z0-9]*([A-Za-z0-9])` => `****$1`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew unfortunately that didn't return anything.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not sure if \K is supported in notepad++.

Comment: Maybe your version is Linux or too old, try `(screen_name:\s[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]*([A-Za-z0-9])`  => `$1****$2`

Comment: Ok this is working! Only problem now is that it is not capturing screen names with underscores. Eg. screen_name: The_BitHound. It is finding just screen_name: The

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use capturing groups in the regex pattern and replacement back references (also called placeholders) in the replacement pattern. Besides, if you want to match letters, digits *and underscores*, use `\w` instead of a custom `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Use

```
(screen_name:\s\w)\w*(\w)
```

The `(screen_name:\s\w)` captures the `screen_name:` and a whitespace into Group 1 later referred to as `$1` from the replacement pattern, `\w*` just matches 0+ word chars and then `(\w)` matches and captures a single word char into Group 2 later referred to as `$2` from the replacement pattern.

Replace with `$1****$2`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/riNTWN/1).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
(screen_name:\s[A-Za-z0-9_])[A-Za-z0-9_]*([A-Za-z0-9_]) => $1****$2
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.